# Make function in class only accessible without calling the class

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, class-method

Let's say I have this class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    @classmethod
    def foo(self):
        return 'hello world!'
```

I use `@classmethod`, so that I can directly call the function without calling the class:

```
>>> A.foo()
'hello world!'
>>>
```

But now I am wondering, since I still can access it with calling the class:

```
>>> A(1).foo()
'hello world!'
>>>
```

Would I be able to make it that it would raise an error if the function `foo` is called from a called class. And only let it to be called without calling the class, like `A.foo()`.

So if I do:

```
A(1).foo()
```

It should give an error.

Comment: Try `@staticmethod`

Comment: In this case why it would be part of the class? It should be function

Comment: @Adithya Already did, that doesn't work too.

Comment: Also, if this will be classmethod, the convention is to use `cls`, not `self`. And as you don't use the class at all it should be static method as suggested by @Adithya. With `@classmethod` the first argument will be the class, not instance.

Comment: You could implement your own descriptor that does this. But why?

Comment: This seems like a very strange thing to want to do.  Most Python programs know that they can call a static method by using an instance of that the appropriate type.  It is much simpler to write `self.my_static_method()` than `MyClassName.my_static_method()`.   What's your use case?

Comment: @FrankYellin Ah, I have a class where I want to do something like in Numpy, where you can do `np.zeros`.

Comment: `np.zeros` is a function in a module, not a static method.

Comment: @FrankYellin Yes I know, but I only have a class.

Comment: But you didn't answer my question.  Why do you care if the user calls a static method using `self`?  You're actively trying to prevent this, and I can't figure out why you care one way or the other.   Using an object to call a static method often makes the code cleaner.

Comment: @FrankYellin Alright, I just have a class like `Sequence([1, 2, 3])` where I can do `Sequence.zeros((1, 2))` but I don't want it to be able to do `Sequence([1, 2, 3]).zeros((1, 2))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functionality of how `classmethod`, `staticmethod` and in fact normal methods are lookedup / bound is implemented via [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors). Similarly, one can define a descriptor that *forbids* lookup/binding on an instance.

A naive implementation of such a descriptor checks whether it is looked up via an instance and raises an error in this case:

```py
class NoInstanceMethod:
    """Descriptor to forbid that other descriptors can be looked up on an instance"""
    def __init__(self, descr, name=None):
        self.descr = descr
        self.name = name

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        # enforce the instance cannot look up the attribute at all
        if instance is not None:
            raise AttributeError(f"{type(instance).__name__!r} has no attribute {self.name!r}")
        # invoke any descriptor we are wrapping
        return self.descr.__get__(instance, owner)
```

This can be applied on top of other descriptors to prevent them from being looked up on an instance. Prominently, it can be combined with `classmethod` or `staticmethod` to prevent using them on an instance:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    @NoInstanceMethod
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        return 'hello world!'


A.foo()     # Stdout: hello world!
A(1).foo()  # AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

---

The above `NoInstanceMethod` is "naive" in that it does not take care of propagating descriptor calls other than `__get__` to its wrapped descriptor. For example, one could propagate `__set_name__` calls to allow the wrapped descriptor to know its name.

Since descriptors are free to (not) implement any of the descriptor methods, this can be supported but needs appropriate error handling. Extend the `NoInstanceMethod` to support whatever descriptor methods are needed in practice.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to override its value upon initialization of a class object to make sure it wouldn't be called from `self`.

```
def raise_(exc):
    raise exc

class A:
    STRICTLY_CLASS_METHODS = [
        "foo",
    ]

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

        for method in self.STRICTLY_CLASS_METHODS:
            # Option 1: Using generator.throw() to raise exception. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/#new-generator-method-throw-type-value-none-traceback-none
            # setattr(self, method, lambda *args, **kwargs: (_ for _ in ()).throw(AttributeError(method)))

            # Option 2: Using a function to raise exception
            setattr(self, method, lambda *args, **kwargs: raise_(AttributeError(method)))

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        return 'hello world!'

    def bar(self):
        return 'hola mundo!', self.a
```

**Output**

```
>>> A.foo()
'hello world!'
>>> a = A(123)
>>> a.bar()
('hola mundo!', 123)
>>> a.foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in <lambda>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in raise_
AttributeError: foo
>>> a.bar()
('hola mundo!', 123)
>>> A(45).bar()
('hola mundo!', 45)
>>> A(6789).foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in <lambda>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in raise_
AttributeError: foo
>>> A.foo()
'hello world!'
```

Comment: This is an incorrect use of `NotImplemented`. It's intended to signify that a reflected method should be attempted, but in this case there is no reflected method to attempt.

Comment: Agree. I updated the answer to remove that and instead use the other option via `delattr` which is more straight-forward. Thank you @wim

Comment: It's even worse.  You can not create an instance of A at all now.  The `AttributeError` here comes from `__init__`, not from accessing the method.

Comment: @wim I was trying to stay away from defining a separate function just to raise. But it seems like the cleanest way. So I reverted back to the first version which uses `setattr` and instead of returning `NotImplemented` (the original issue), I now just raised an exception. I think it fully resolves all issues now :)